Convert Structured xml to table using python
I have a custom xml file where I should fetch only details about entities and its corresponding attributes and convert it into a tabular format. Here is a sample of the xml file.
<ESpace Key="ESpace:y7vmLUGpAMoLhw4MvpnAPg" Name="Onboarding_Core" UserProviderEspace="Users" DefaultThemeNewRuntime="ThemeReference:rQ3WUJw0o0+BC9ZDjXD7uA" DefaultTransition="Fade" UseCookies="Yes" WebScreenRenderingMode="HTML5" ModuleType="CrossDevice">
<Actions>
</Actions>
<Entities>
<Entity Key="Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" Public="Yes" Name="Document">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Long Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:ypRA49SJBkexc+ICR12zdw" Length="50" Name="Name" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:mdWB6OaTkE26BwxQRRfbBg" Name="CreatedOn" DataType="Date Time"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:W0foZDFa5kme6QySnTNEMA" Name="Binary" DataType="Binary Data"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>
<Entity Key="Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA" IsStaticEntity="Yes" IsMultitenant="No" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw" Public="Yes" Name="DateFormat" Folder="Folder:SErnhCWKOUKpp39VDQVVcg">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:Q0S8yDbafEi+YMF0rXnbvg" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Format" DataType="Text" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:XUw_zMWoZki2qWuZcYRizw" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Example" DataType="Text" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:YpcYFT5YNUKxqaYLZOe6qA" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Order" DataType="Integer" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:3QRHk0Wl7kuwg4gmzIs8yw" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="IsActive" DataType="Boolean" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>

There are totally 28 entities(tables) each has its own set of attributes (columns) to it. I want to display each entity with its corresponding attributes in a table format for all 28 entities.
I'm a beginner in python. I tried the below python code to get the first entity name and store its corresponding columns/Attributes into a dictionary, but what happens is the root.findall of attribute fetches all the attributes present in the xml file not just the one corresponding to the first entity. How to fetch the attributes for each entity separately and get it into table format.? There are totally 28 entities.
table_list=[]
Attribute_list=[]
for entity_list in root.findall('.//Entity'):
    entity_dict={}
    entity_dict['Entity_Name']=entity_list.get('Name')
    print(entity_dict)
    for attribute_list in root.findall('.//Attribute'):
        attribute_dict={}
        attribute_dict['Attribute_Name']=attribute_list.get('Name')
        for child_elem_1 in attribute_list:
            attribute_dict[child_elem_1.tag]=child_elem_1.text
        Attribute_list.append(attribute_dict)
    print(Attribute_list)
df= pd.DataFrame(Attribute_list)
print(df.head(10))


What do you want the result to look like?

Here is an example how you can make a dataframe from the XML snippet using beautifulsoup:
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = """\
<ESpace Key="ESpace:y7vmLUGpAMoLhw4MvpnAPg" Name="Onboarding_Core" UserProviderEspace="Users" DefaultThemeNewRuntime="ThemeReference:rQ3WUJw0o0+BC9ZDjXD7uA" DefaultTransition="Fade" UseCookies="Yes" WebScreenRenderingMode="HTML5" ModuleType="CrossDevice">
<Actions>
</Actions>
<Entities>
<Entity Key="Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" Public="Yes" Name="Document">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Long Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:ypRA49SJBkexc+ICR12zdw" Length="50" Name="Name" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:mdWB6OaTkE26BwxQRRfbBg" Name="CreatedOn" DataType="Date Time"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:W0foZDFa5kme6QySnTNEMA" Name="Binary" DataType="Binary Data"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>
<Entity Key="Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA" IsStaticEntity="Yes" IsMultitenant="No" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw" Public="Yes" Name="DateFormat" Folder="Folder:SErnhCWKOUKpp39VDQVVcg">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:Q0S8yDbafEi+YMF0rXnbvg" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Format" DataType="Text" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:XUw_zMWoZki2qWuZcYRizw" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Example" DataType="Text" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:YpcYFT5YNUKxqaYLZOe6qA" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Order" DataType="Integer" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:3QRHk0Wl7kuwg4gmzIs8yw" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="IsActive" DataType="Boolean" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>

</Entities>
</ESpace>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

out = []
for e in soup.select("Entity"):
    attrs = {}
    for a in e.select("Attribute"):
        out.append({"Entity Name": e["Name"], **a.attrs})

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df)

Prints:
  Entity Name                               Key IsMandatory       Name      DataType IsAutoNumber Length DeleteRule
0    Document  Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g         Yes         Id  Long Integer          Yes    NaN        NaN
1    Document  Attribute:ypRA49SJBkexc+ICR12zdw         NaN       Name          Text          NaN     50        NaN
2    Document  Attribute:mdWB6OaTkE26BwxQRRfbBg         NaN  CreatedOn     Date Time          NaN    NaN        NaN
3    Document  Attribute:W0foZDFa5kme6QySnTNEMA         NaN     Binary   Binary Data          NaN    NaN        NaN
4  DateFormat  Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw         Yes         Id       Integer          Yes    NaN     Ignore
5  DateFormat  Attribute:Q0S8yDbafEi+YMF0rXnbvg         Yes     Format          Text          NaN     50     Ignore
6  DateFormat  Attribute:XUw_zMWoZki2qWuZcYRizw         Yes    Example          Text          NaN     50     Ignore
7  DateFormat  Attribute:YpcYFT5YNUKxqaYLZOe6qA         Yes      Order       Integer          NaN    NaN     Ignore
8  DateFormat  Attribute:3QRHk0Wl7kuwg4gmzIs8yw         Yes   IsActive       Boolean          NaN    NaN     Ignore


Use .findall('.//Attribute') on each entity, not on the root.
Below is an example:
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

xml = '''\
<ESpace Key="ESpace:y7vmLUGpAMoLhw4MvpnAPg" Name="Onboarding_Core" UserProviderEspace="Users" DefaultThemeNewRuntime="ThemeReference:rQ3WUJw0o0+BC9ZDjXD7uA" DefaultTransition="Fade" UseCookies="Yes" WebScreenRenderingMode="HTML5" ModuleType="CrossDevice">
<Actions>
</Actions>
<Entities>
<Entity Key="Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" Public="Yes" Name="Document">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Long Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:ypRA49SJBkexc+ICR12zdw" Length="50" Name="Name" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:mdWB6OaTkE26BwxQRRfbBg" Name="CreatedOn" DataType="Date Time"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:W0foZDFa5kme6QySnTNEMA" Name="Binary" DataType="Binary Data"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>
<Entity Key="Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA" IsStaticEntity="Yes" IsMultitenant="No" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw" Public="Yes" Name="DateFormat" Folder="Folder:SErnhCWKOUKpp39VDQVVcg">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:Q0S8yDbafEi+YMF0rXnbvg" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Format" DataType="Text" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:XUw_zMWoZki2qWuZcYRizw" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Example" DataType="Text" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:YpcYFT5YNUKxqaYLZOe6qA" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Order" DataType="Integer" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:3QRHk0Wl7kuwg4gmzIs8yw" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="IsActive" DataType="Boolean" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>
</Entities>
</ESpace>
'''

root = et.fromstring(xml)
entity_list = root.findall('.//Entity')
entity_names = [e.get('Name') for e in entity_list]
attribute_lists = []
for entity in entity_list:
    attributes = [a.get('Name') for a in entity.findall('.//Attribute')]
    attribute_lists.append(attributes)
df= pd.DataFrame({'Entity':entity_names, 'Attributes':attribute_lists})
print(df)

Output:
       Entity                              Attributes
0    Document           [Id, Name, CreatedOn, Binary]
1  DateFormat  [Id, Format, Example, Order, IsActive]


Here's an approach using pd.read_xml:

get a DataFrame entities using xpath='.//Entity' with attrs_only=True. Setting column 'identifier' as index with df.set_index, and applying df.add_prefix will be useful for df.merge below.
Also get a DataFrame attributes, simply using xpath='.//Attribute'.
Now, apply df.merge and benefit from the fact that attributes['Key'] will have two unique matches on entities.index, signifying the start of each consecutive 'entity'.
Finally, apply df.ffill on the columns that originate from entities.

Code
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

entities = (pd.read_xml(StringIO(xml_string), 
                        xpath='.//Entity', 
                        attrs_only=True)
            .set_index('Identifier')
            .add_prefix('Entity_')
            )

attributes = pd.read_xml(StringIO(xml_string), xpath='.//Attribute')

cols = ['Entity_Key', 'Entity_Name']

df_xml = (entities[cols].merge(attributes, 
                               left_index=True, 
                               right_on='Key', 
                               how='right')
          )

df_xml[cols] = df_xml[cols].ffill()

df_xml

Output
                      Entity_Key Entity_Name  \
0  Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA    Document   
1  Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA    Document   
2  Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA    Document   
3  Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA    Document   
4  Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA  DateFormat   
5  Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA  DateFormat   
6  Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA  DateFormat   
7  Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA  DateFormat   
8  Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA  DateFormat   

                                Key IsMandatory       Name      DataType  \
0  Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g         Yes         Id  Long Integer   
1  Attribute:ypRA49SJBkexc+ICR12zdw        None       Name          Text   
2  Attribute:mdWB6OaTkE26BwxQRRfbBg        None  CreatedOn     Date Time   
3  Attribute:W0foZDFa5kme6QySnTNEMA        None     Binary   Binary Data   
4  Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw         Yes         Id       Integer   
5  Attribute:Q0S8yDbafEi+YMF0rXnbvg         Yes     Format          Text   
6  Attribute:XUw_zMWoZki2qWuZcYRizw         Yes    Example          Text   
7  Attribute:YpcYFT5YNUKxqaYLZOe6qA         Yes      Order       Integer   
8  Attribute:3QRHk0Wl7kuwg4gmzIs8yw         Yes   IsActive       Boolean   

  IsAutoNumber  Length DeleteRule  
0          Yes     NaN       None  
1         None    50.0       None  
2         None     NaN       None  
3         None     NaN       None  
4          Yes     NaN     Ignore  
5         None    50.0     Ignore  
6         None    50.0     Ignore  
7         None     NaN     Ignore  
8         None     NaN     Ignore  

Sample used
xml_string = """<ESpace Key="ESpace:y7vmLUGpAMoLhw4MvpnAPg" Name="Onboarding_Core" UserProviderEspace="Users" DefaultThemeNewRuntime="ThemeReference:rQ3WUJw0o0+BC9ZDjXD7uA" DefaultTransition="Fade" UseCookies="Yes" WebScreenRenderingMode="HTML5" ModuleType="CrossDevice">
<Actions>
</Actions>
<Entities>
<Entity Key="Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" Public="Yes" Name="Document">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Long Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:ypRA49SJBkexc+ICR12zdw" Length="50" Name="Name" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:mdWB6OaTkE26BwxQRRfbBg" Name="CreatedOn" DataType="Date Time"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:W0foZDFa5kme6QySnTNEMA" Name="Binary" DataType="Binary Data"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>
<Entity Key="Entity:6NuECH7xe06M250tQsPsJA" IsStaticEntity="Yes" IsMultitenant="No" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw" Public="Yes" Name="DateFormat" Folder="Folder:SErnhCWKOUKpp39VDQVVcg">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:jBExnTjCy0GOtV5fZZG0pw" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:Q0S8yDbafEi+YMF0rXnbvg" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Format" DataType="Text" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:XUw_zMWoZki2qWuZcYRizw" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Example" DataType="Text" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:YpcYFT5YNUKxqaYLZOe6qA" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Order" DataType="Integer" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:3QRHk0Wl7kuwg4gmzIs8yw" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="IsActive" DataType="Boolean" DeleteRule="Ignore"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>
</Entities>
</ESpace>"""

